# Visual Studio 2012 : AJAX Toolkit is shallow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and create a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Project. After that, I install `ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit` by using `Package Manager Console` by typing :

```
Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit
```

After that, I open a sample cshtml file. In my toolkit, I can use `HTML Toolkit`, but `AJAX Toolkit`, I can see it, but all items in this toolkit is shallow (dark gray), and I cannot drag and drop it to source screen.

Comment: This is because MVC does not use "controls" like those in a WebForms app -> in order to use drag/drop controls, you would need to create a WebForms application.  The AjaxControlToolkit is WebForms only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax Control Toolkit is meant to be used with WebForms projects, not MVC.  I would imagine that is why it's not working.  Use jQuery, and jQuery UI, instead.

Comment: thanks :) I have tried WebForm project and it's right. So, I must use Jquery UI instead ? and can you explain me that I cannot use Ajax Control Toolkit in MVC Project please ? thanks :)

Comment: @hqt The Ajax Control Toolkit defines reusable ASP.NET server controls, which render markup to the browser.  UserControls don't exist in MVC.  The problem with UserControls is they couple too many responsibilities together.  The whole point of using MVC is to keep things loosely coupled.  So for example, your view should have no idea how your model is populated.

Comment: @hqt As for jQuery UI, it features a rich set of widgets, amongst other things, so it'll provide you a similar mechanism for doing the same thing.  I'm sure there are plenty of others you can use.

Comment: thanks :D i understand now. just another point, that I google that have a way that hybrid between MVC and Web Form. Should I come to this way (does exist something better ? ) or just use one framework for this. ? thanks :)

Comment: @hqt Personally, since moving to MVC, I've not wanted to even look at WebForms again, but that's a decision only you can make.